# vec3.unproject() mouse collision problems

Tags: javascript, math, webgl, collision

```
var fNearZ  = -100.0;
var farZ    = 100.0;
var fZoom   = 10.0;
var iR      = this.iWidth/fZoom;
var iL      = (this.iWidth/fZoom)*(-1);
var iT      = this.iHeight/fZoom;
var iB      = (this.iHeight/fZoom)*(-1);

var pMatrix     = new mat4.ortho(iL, iR, iB, iT, fNearZ, farZ);
var mvMatrix    = new mat4.create();

mat4.identity(mvMatrix);
zI.debug(mat4.str(mvMatrix),{'grp':'mv_before','style':'color:#060;'});

mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [0.0, 0.0, -50.0]);
mat4.scale(mvMatrix, [3, 3, 3]);

zI.debug(vec3.unproject([
        parseFloat(this.pLastMouse.x-this.iLeft),
        parseFloat(this.pLastMouse.y-this.iTop),
        0
    ],
    mvMatrix,
    pMatrix,
    [
        0,
        0,
        this.iWidth,
        this.iHeight
    ]),{'grp':'dest____','style':'color:#00F;'});

this.setMatrices(pMatrix, mvMatrix);
//After this line, buffers will be set
```

[image: Screen of 16x16 Planes with 0.1 offset between]
SCREEN URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/au2ac.png

Today I've tried to realize my mouse-collision with the new version of gl-matrix, providing vec3.unproject. What I want is to get the z-world-coordinate of the mouse-position. As you can see on the Screenshot, the x and y coordinates are ok, but the z-coordinate is always 50, no matter where the cursor befinds.

Each of the planes is 1.0x1.0 with 0.1 space between.

When I add rotation or translation on the Y-Axis, I'm receiving wrong(?) x- and y- coordinates from unproject. I think the way I handle mvMatrix and pMatrix is wrong. Can anyone please help me?

**EDIT**
Without using .translate() and .scale() functions I'm getting the correct values of zNear and zFar right now, still don't know if the coordinates are correct, when I apply these functions to the modelview-matrix. What's still missing is the intersection-calculation.

**Link to my source:** http://jsfiddle.net/matthoz/vucAq/

Comment: I should mention that the unproject function in glMatrix is very new and has not undergone a lot of rigorous testing across multiple scenarios yet. It's entirely possible that I goofed something up. Would it be possible to post your source somewhere so I can cross check it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/matthoz/vucAq/ <- Please do not laugh at me ;) - Texture doesn't work on jsfiddle. But i can tell you, your code works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the "z-world-coordinate of the mouse-position" it's not a coordinate but an infinite amount of them (the imaginary line that shoots from the x,y position of the mouse). I'm guessing 50 it's an arbitrary value or the 50.0 you've got on the mvMatrix.

If you make two unproject calls with zFar and zNear you will get a finite rect which you can start to work on.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've added a second debug-call for unproject and gave zNear to vec[2] in the first call and zFar to vec[2] in the second call. The result for z is 6716.666... (zNear) and -6616.666... for zFar :S

Comment: Hmmm, what happens if you make the call with the Z value of the plane?

Comment: http://myweb.lmu.edu/dondi/share/cg/unproject-explained.pdf

Here's a lot of theory about how the unProject works, first of all try zNear=0 and zFar=1 and let us know the results

Comment: `[parseFloat(this.pLastMouse.x-this.iLeft),parseFloat(this.pLastMouse.y-this.iTop),parseFloat(0)]` for the first call (zNear) and `[parseFloat(this.pLastMouse.x-this.iLeft),parseFloat(this.pLastMouse.y-this.iTop),parseFloat(1)]` for the second (zFar): Result 50.000... for zNear(0) and -16.666 for zFar(1) - Did I insert zNear=0 and zFar=1 on the right place, or should I replace `var fNearZ=-100.0; var farZ=100.0;` in top of mat4.ortho? BTW - TY for linking the unproject-pdf!

Comment: I've read the document, you've posted. If the values i've got (50 and -16) are correctly representing zNear an zFar of the ray (What I don't believe), there is still missing code to calculate the intersection, right?

Comment: Yes indeed, the intersection code is missing but shouldn't be a problem. I'm thinking if there might be somre problem with the transformations, what are the values without them?

Comment: Without .translate and .scale, the Results are: 100 when `vec[2]=0` and -100 when `vec[2]=1` - Just like I difined my planes `var fNearZ=-100.0; var farZ=100.0;` Seems good to me, but shouldn't it be -100 if vec[2] is 0 and 100 if vec[2]=1? TY so far :), but I still hace no idea how to continue. :S

Comment: For now I'd assume that the unproject returns the correct ray and try to intersect it with your plane. See if the Z value is correct.

Comment: Sorry, could you be so kind to give me a little example on how to intersect the ray with my plane? I've no idea how to do this.

Comment: Start here: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/planeline/, it's simple math and shouldn't be much of a problem

Comment: Of course I will :) - When I'm done, I'll post the working code.

Comment: Still having the same problem... Do I have to make an intersection-test on every triangle? I have to know the coordinates of them, right?